# Multiple group rows for same value in SSRS matrix report

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SQL query that generates output like this:

Category   ID    Hour   Calls   Sales

--------   ---   ----   -----   -----

A ,,   6409,,  9AM,,  5,,      2

A ,,   6409,,  12PM,, 8,,      3

A ,,   6409,,  2PM,,  4,,      1

B ,,   6409,,  1AM,,  2,,      0

I used it for generating Matrix based SSRS report with following format:

### Category

```
           HOUR
        ---------------------------
```

ID    ....        Calls  ..  Sales

-----        .   -------   ...------

So final output should look like following:

(Page1 for Category 'A')

A

```
      9AM      12PM      2PM
```

6409  ...  5,,,2 ..........    8,,,3  ..........   4,,,1

(Page2 for Category 'B')

A

```
       1AM
```

6409  ......  2,,,0

---

But my report is giving me this result:

(Page1 for Category 'A')

A

```
      9AM      12PM      2PM
```

6409  .....  5,,,2 ..........    .....  ..........   .....

6409  .....  ..... ..........    8,,,3  ..........   4,,,1

(Page2 for Category 'B')

A

```
       1AM
```

6409  ......  2,,,0

It prints same ID multiple times. I want only one row for each ID in each page. I've tried making a parent group based on ID, but since there can be more than one ID, so that didn't work. Kindly help me in identifying the issue.

[I am using ssrs 2008]

Comment: Please add your code so people can try and reproduce

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I don't if i mistakenly made wrong settings or is it something else, but SSRS was auto formatting the values in 'ID' for grouping purposes. And while doing so, it would append extra space with some IDs, hence would show it under separate row. I removed those extra spaces and now everything is fine.

Thanks NirMH.